# Dictionary count based on sub-string

Tags: python, string, dictionary

I am trying to open a file, iterate over each line, and do a count of a specific word in each line to add to a Dictionary.

For the sake of this question, the file has values in it that look like this:

```
From some.email@address.ac.za Sat Jan  5 09:14:16 2008
From some.email@address.ac.za Sat Jan  5 09:14:16 2008
From some.email@address.ac.za Fri Jan  5 09:14:16 2008
From some.email@address.ac.za Wed Jan  5 09:14:16 2008
From some.email@address.ac.za Tue Jan  5 09:14:16 2008
From some.email@address.ac.za Sat Jan  5 09:14:16 2008
From some.email@address.ac.za Sat Jan  5 09:14:16 2008
From some.email@address.ac.za Sat Jan  5 09:14:16 2008
```

What I want to do is read in the file,  iterate over each line, and keep a count of the days of the week and return that in a Dictionary. So the results would look something like this:

```
{'Sat': 5, 'Fri': 1, 'Wed': 1, 'Tue': 1}
```

I have it to the point of reading in the file and splitting at the whitespace, and appending to a list.  After that I am stuck and can't drill down to that specific section of test in each list.

Any ideas?

```
fname = input('Enter the file name: ')
try:
    fhand = open(fname)
except:
    print('File cannot be opened:', fname)
    exit()

counts = dict()
l1 = []
for line in fhand:
    line = line.split()
    l1.append(line)
for date in l1:
    for day in date:
        if day[2] not in counts:
            counts[day] = 1
        else:
            counts[day] += 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from collections import defaultdict
fname = input('Enter the file name: ')
try:
    fhand = open(fname)
except:
    print('File cannot be opened:', fname)
    exit()

counts = defaultdict(int)
l1 = []
for line in fhand:
    line = line.split()
    for word in line:
        if word in ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thrus', 'Fri', 'Sat']:
            counts[word] += 1
print(counts)
```

After reading each line and splitting it into words, you can check if the word is a day name, and if it is, then update the value corresponding to that day.

Comment: what does defaultdict do?

Comment: Check documentation here -> https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html

Comment: oh that is much simpler isn't it, rather than trying to slice to find the day of the week.  Thanks.  Ill accept once I am able to

Comment: @MariaNazari a defaultdict provides that an unknown key will not raise a KeyError. Instead, it returns a default value.